# How to remain stick to a php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing the level of the question through query string to the page. Next, I am prompting user to give the answer from the option. Now, if the answer is correct, score is incremented. Now the issue is that if the answer is wrong, I am not getting any thing in browser.

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    if ( isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $qid = $_POST['qid'];
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        // $range= $_POST['range'] ;
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','1234','islamic')
        or die('unable to connect');

        $query = "select * from question where qid = '$qid' ";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if ( $answer == $row['answer'])
        {
            // echo 'Congrats, Your answer is correct.'.$_COOKIE['username'];
            @$score = ++$_COOKIE['score'];
            setcookie('score',$score);
        }
        @$page = ++$_COOKIE['page'];

        if ( @$page == 4)
        {
            echo 'score is '.$_COOKIE['score'];
            setcookie('score',0);
            setcookie('page',0);

            echo 'Go to <a href="index.php"> Home </a>';
            exit();
        }

        setcookie('page',$page);

    }

    if ( isset($_GET['level']))
    {
        $_SESSION['level'] = $_GET['level'];
    }
        $level = $_SESSION['level'];


    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','1234','islamic')
    or die('unable to connect');

    // $query = "Select * from question";
    // $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    // $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $range = rand(0,6); 

    $query = "select * from question where level = '$level' limit $range,1";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    while ( ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) )
    {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3> <?php echo $row['sawal']; ?></h3>

                <form  method = "POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                    <input type="radio"  name=" answer" value="A" ><?php echo $row['A']; ?><br>
                    <input type="radio"  name=" answer" value="B" ><?php echo $row['B']; ?><br>
                    <input type="radio"  name=" answer" value="C" ><?php echo $row['C']; ?><br>
                    <input type="radio"  name=" answer" value="D" ><?php echo $row['D']; ?><br>

                    <input type="hidden" name = "qid" value="<?php echo $row['qid'] ?>">
                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name = "range" value="<?php  $range ?>"> -->

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ANSWER"/>

                </form>

        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
 ?>
```

Comment: You are storing the score in a cookie?  You do realize that this allows a user with any technical sense to be able to modify their own score, right?

Comment: I hope those aren't your real MySQL credentials. `root:1234`?

Comment: @cdhowie I am a novice to Php. What should I use?

Comment: @esqew These are real :P

Comment: @user3641971 That's bad, especially if your website is publicly-facing: now your MySQL credentials are **online** for the world to see and will remain there *forever* because they've probably already been cached by Google. Change them now!

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to connect more than once to DB.

Comment: @esqew Thanks.But I am running my site on localserver.

Comment: @user3641971 I would suggest using [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to store data like this.  Cookies should rarely be used, and when you do use them be aware that cookie data is sent by the browser, and this is something you have no control over -- anything a browser can send, a user can manipulate.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: why are you using [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)?

Comment: So that error is not displayed when I encounter these variables first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You script doesn't display anything if the database query returns no results.

Get rid of the while and simply use $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);